# how to splict array object in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I m getting following result through query  in nodejs.

```
data = [
    {
        AValuv: 6,
        BValuv: 8928,
        CValuv: 2553
    }
];
```

now I through forEach how to split them in two array and push them in the to get the required result.

```js
let name=[];
let value=[];
name=[AValuv, BValuv, CValuv]
value=[6, 8928, 2553]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty easy in **JavaScript** you can use `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` to get the keys and the values of the object.

```js
data=[
{
 AValuv: 6,
 BValuv: 8928,
 CValuv: 2553
}
  ]

data.forEach((elem) => {
   let vals = Object.values(elem);
   let keys = Object.keys(elem);
   console.log(vals)
   console.log(keys)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```js
let data = [{'AValuv': 6, 'BValuv': 8928, 'CValuv': 2553}]

let name = [];
let value = [];
data.forEach(item => {
   Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
       name.push(key);
       value.push(item[key]);
   });
});

console.log(name);
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.forEeach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) once on the array, and then parse the objects with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/entries) and use [`Array.prototype.forEeach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach) once again.

```js
const data = [{
    AValuv: 6,
    BValuv: 8928,
    CValuv: 2553
  }
];

const name = [];
const value = [];
data.forEach(x => Object.entries(x).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    name.push(k);
    value.push(v);
  })
);

console.log(name);
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [
    {
        AValuv: 6,
        BValuv: 8928,
        CValuv: 2553
    }
];

let name = [];
let value = [];

data.forEach(o => {
  name.push(...Object.keys(o));
  value.push(...Object.values(o));
});

console.log(name, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following

```js
data = [
   {
  AValuv: 6,
 BValuv: 8928,
 CValuv: 2553
}
]

let name = Object.keys(data[0])
let value = Object.values(data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
const data = [{
  AValuv: 6,
  BValuv: 8928,
  CValuv: 2553
}];


let name=[];
let value=[];

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data[0])) {
  name.push(key);
  value.push(value);
}
```

For more information see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries